# Python: Join all the first elements of list of strings, second elements of list of strings and so on

Tags: python

The input is a nested list of strings and the output should be the list of strings with first element of the input strings joined, second element of all the input strings and so on..

```
inputList = [["o" , "t" ,"t", "", "",""],["n", "w", "hr", "", ""],["e", "o", "e", ""],["", "", "e", ""]]
outputList = ['one', 'two', 'three', '', '']
```

This is how I brute forced it.

```
listStr = ["", "", "", "", ""]
for i in range(0,len(IN)):
    for j in range(0,len(IN)):
        listStr[i] += IN[j][i]
```

What is a better way with better time complexity and space complexity to get the required output instead of bruteforcing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cleaner way at least is to transpose the inputList:

```
list(zip(*inputList))

[('o', 'n', 'e', ''),
 ('t', 'w', 'o', ''),
 ('t', 'hr', 'e', 'e'),
 ('', '', '', '')]
```

and concatenate them into a word:

```
[''.join(word) for word in zip(*inputList)]

['one', 'two', 'three', '']
```